# Home furnace not kicking on or staying on

Tags: furnace

I have a furnace question.  Our house has an Amana furnace and it won't seem to kick on.

For context, the temperature in the house is around 60 degrees or so. When setting the thermostat higher, a few things occur.  There is a clicking sound and through the hole in the furnace door I can see the ignitor glow a very bright orange but then the burners do not ignite, the ignitor stops glowing and the fan seems to stop as well.  This usually happens three times until it stops trying completely and then the red LED light, which was on before, now blinks every three seconds.  Any help would be appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever hear the gas start flowing? Do you have any other gas appliances (e.g., water heater, dryer)?

Comment: Yes I do.  I should have mentioned that on very rare occasions one of the burners on the furnace, the one farthest to the right to be exact, will ignite for a brief time.  So I know that in some cases it does appear that the gas is reaching the burners, just it does not seem constant that they ignite.  We do have other gas appliances that are working fine.

Comment: That rules out an overall gas supply problem. Which leaves any number of possible limit switches, temperature sensors, etc.

Comment: Find the model number, go to the amana site (maytag owns amana) and look for the meaning of the blinking. This is most likely the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Gas flows through a rail to reach all the burners so if only one burner is lighting, that usually means the pressure is too low so the regulator needs checked by a professional.